# application crashing when using getview in listfragment

Tags: android

I'm learning how to use ListFragment and the application is crashing when it runs the following code:

```
public class profileListFragment extends ListFragment {

String[] countries = new String[] {"USA", "China"};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countries);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    View retView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container,  savedInstanceState);

    return retView;//super.onCreateView(inflater, container,  savedInstanceState);
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView I, View v, int position, long id){
    I.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    I.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_light);
}
}
```

I know it is because of the getListView() statement since when I remove it it doesn't crash...

Any help much appreciated

```
I/ActivityManager(352): START {cmp=myapp.app/.loadProfile u=0} from pid 24295

E/AndroidRuntime(24295): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myapp.app/myapp.app.loadProfile}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment

E/AndroidRuntime(24295): at myapp.app.loadProfile.onCreate(loadProfile.java:12)

E/AndroidRuntime(24295): at myapp.app.profileListFragment.onCreateView(profileListFragment.java:19)

11-10 22:15:01.002: W/ActivityManager(352):   Force finishing activity myapp.app/.loadProfile
```

Comment: Post the logcat trace for the crash.

Comment: hm... i downloaded catlog but have no idea how to get the logcat... also, I should mention I'm running it on a tablet not on an emulator, not sure if that matters...

Comment: Did you actually read the instructions for catlog? Or try the menu options? You can email the whole of the logcat output to yourself then copy/paste it here (although please only copy/paste the parts relevant to the crash). Alternatively, connect the tablet using USB and use DDMS.

Comment: Probably because your list is not inflated when you do getListView in onCreate(). Check for inflater is null and if its is inflate  `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, container, false);`

Comment: hm... didn't know about DDMS and catlog would complain about sudo permissions.... anyway updated what I think is the relevant messages using DDMS, if something else is needed please let me know. thanks

Comment: The problem is in your xml - check for correctness of class paths in your xml

Comment: @ Slartibartfast I don't have a layout, my understanding was that ListFragment kind of inherits a ListView layout by itself as described here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html  "ListFragment has a default layout that consists of a single list view"

Comment: Check line # 6 - should be something like this `<fragment
        class= "com.something.fragment"` - see if you have the correct and full class path

Comment: are you referring to this? `<fragment
        android:id="@+id/list_profiles_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="myapp.app.profileListFragment" >
    </fragment>`

Comment: Yes see if your class path is correct . Also try `inflater.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, container);` before View `retView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container,  savedInstanceState);`

Comment: the class path is correct and anything I add after getListView won't change anything since the program has already crashed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an xml that looked like this:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" >

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and then inflate it and do a findViewById on that view looking for android.R.id.list and then have my ListView handler I needed in the first place. code snippet is this:

```
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_load_profile_list_layout,container, false);
    ListView lv = (ListView) retView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lv.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_light);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```